how to ffmpeg encode as 6-bit color?
How to ffmpeg encode as 6bit color?
There are many pix_fmt, but i do not see any 6-bit.
6-bit exists as 64-colors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monochrome_and_RGB_color_formats#6-bit_RGB
$ ffmpeg -i INPUT.MP4 -pix_fmt rgb6 6-bit-output-test.mp4
[...]
Unknown pixel format requested: rgb6.


although i prefer an official pix_fmt, i have the following workaround/solution:
generate palette:
wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/RGB_6bits_palette.png
ffmpeg -y -i RGB_6bits_palette.png -vf palettegen=max_colors=64:reserve_transparent=1 my64colorpalette.png

encode with dithering:
ffmpeg -i INPUT.MP4 -i my64colorpalette.png -lavfi paletteuse -c:a copy 64color-output.mp4

or encode without dithering:
ffmpeg -i INPUT.MP4 -i my64colorpalette.png -lavfi paletteuse=dither=none -c:a copy 64color-output-no-dither.mp4

